# lxc+btrfs - Create and then remove a dir w/ circular symbolic link causes stale file handle

Tags: btrfs, lxc

Environment:

- debian jessie inside a virtualbox VM
- using root account in guest and in containers
- lxc container inside the VM
- lxc container root file system on btrfs
- works fine when running in the VM guest, but not in container
- works fine when running in the container when in a folder that exists in the base btrfs file system
- fails when running in the container in a new subdirectory (delta from base)

I have a bizarre issue that surfaced when trying to install ruby from ruby-build. In the install process, it runs a configure script that, somewhere in it's 25,000+ lines, runs something like the following:

```
mkdir d
ln -s f d
rm d/f
rmdir d
```

After that, the current directory handle is stale and running 'ls' results in:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Stale file handle
```

After trying to nail it down a bit, I see it only happens inside the container and only when running from a folder that doesn't exist in the base image.

For example, the base image has /root already, so if I run the 4 commands from /root, it works fine. However, if I run from /root/somesubdir it fails. The same thing happens in /tmp and /opt (only one / mount, nothing special for /tmp or /opt) where it works fine for /tmp or /opt, but not for some subdir I create inside it.

If I instead run the command inside /run which is a tmpfs mount, it works just fine inside the container in subdirectories.

Here's my mounts:

```
Filesystem                         1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/var/lib/lxc/base_container/rootfs  37747708 20436096  16331024  56% /
udev                                   10240        0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                                4097824       12   4097812   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                4097824   106600   3991224   3% /run
tmpfs                                   5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                4097824        0   4097824   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I assume it's some quirk from the created d/f file that's a circular symbolic link to itself.

Any ideas on what's going wrong or how to fix it?